# formatting nav bar (bringing back to same row)

Tags: html, css

EDIT: My source is at https://bitbucket.org/kunaladhia01/studentaccounts/src

css file is under static/css/main.css

html is at template/student/index.html

So far, my code looks like this

```
 <div class="content-wrap">
 <header class="hero-area" id="home">

  <div class="container">
      <div>

        <div class="nav navbar-inverse sticky-navigation navbar-fixed-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="200">
          <div class="container">
          <nav>
            <div class="nav-wrapper">
              <form onsubmit="return false;">
                <div class="input-field">
                  <input id="search" type="search" required placeholder="Search">
                  <label for="search"><i class="material-icons">search</i></label>
                  <i class="material-icons">close</i>
                </div>
              </form>
              <button class="menu-icon"  id="open-button">
                <i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i>
              </button> 
            </div>
          </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

There are two problems I have so far, which should be an easy fix, but its been 3 hours and I still have no progress

zippyshare com/v/h2ThM1Xi/file.html

zippyshare com/v/0h9KvaQI/file.html

(add the dot in)

I need to make the menu icon go into the same row as the search bar (class="row" wont work) and there's this blue bar behind the search bar, which i have no idea where it came from

Comment: Are you using [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for formatting?  Also can you include the complete [tag:HTML].  I don't see the closing `header` tag.

Comment: How can we help you without your CSS and whole HTML?

Comment: Can't you just paste code here? Or create a fiddle? I don't have access to your bitbucket..

Comment: @makshh the html is in templates (basehomefinal.html and /student/index.html) and the css and js is under the static folder
http://www31.zippyshare.com/v/OmU3KBZz/file.html